# Rotate a portrait (vertical) video 180 degrees on iPhone

Tags: iphone

Somehow a vertical video I shot was saved upside down. The phone was not upside down when I shot it.

Anyway, I want to rotate it to it's correct orientation. It was suggested iMovie iOS could do this. Aside from using iMovie on iPhone for the first time and finding the interface abysmal and far from intuitive, it appears that it can not do this. Anything I do in iMovie ends up cropped to a square.

How do I flip a vertical video on the iPhone without a 3rd party app?

Comment: Any reason you don’t want a third party app? What if it’s free or very cheap?

Comment: moreso just a preference to not install an app to do something that I feel should be available out of the box on iPhone. I do have a major gripe with Apple for often failing to include basic editing abilities for stuff like this. I am guessing it's not possible without installing a 3rd party app.

Comment: It’s annoying. Apple hide a lot of functions in the name of “simplicity”.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don’t think it’s possible without an app.

I know it’s not the answer you wanted, but I have had some success with “Video Rotate And Flip by Wander Bit”, which didn’t exactly break the bank at 79p.